# How CPU architecture 8085 and 8086 (and also cpu based on 8086) differ and categorized?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

Reading across difference lineage of CPU created by intel , many questions aroused in my head that need to be solved . The questions are as follow :

In terms of what difference that makes both the architecture of 8085 and 8086 differ that makes intel name both of this architecture differently ?

Note : My friend told me 8085 is an 8-bit microprocessor but 8086 is a 16-bit processor , this is what makes them different from each other and that's why , one is called 8085 and the other is called 8086 . But as far as I know most of the CPU we're using right now are currently called 80x86 architecture based on the 8086 cpu and it has 32-bits version and also 64-bits , in my honest opinion this shows my friend's explanation is wrong because all these CPUs are still called the 80x86 architecture although the bits are difference.

As a follow up, what properties did 80x86 architecture inherited from 8086, why doesn't Intel just call the CPU 8087 but instead it's called 80186 , 80286 , 80386 and etc?

Comment: [8087](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8087) was already in use for a math coprocessor.

Comment: Related: [The start of x86: Intel 8080 vs Intel 8086?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6500)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 8085 is **very** different from the 8086. They have different registers, very different instruction sets, they can address different amounts of memory, they handle interrupts differently, etc etc. And, yes, the 8085 is an 8-bit CPU, while the 8086 is 16-bit.

80x86 (or simply x86) commonly refers to 8086/8088, 80186, 80286, 80386, 80486, Pentium. This architecture, as outlined above, is very different from that of 8085/8080 (and quite similar, but more powerful Z80). Why would one want to name entirely different things with the same name?

The 8087 is not a CPU, it's an FPU. It's completely different from the 8086. It became a functional part of the 80486 CPU, however. Before then it was an optional PC part. There were multiple FPUs in the series, e.g.: 8087, 80287, 80387. And that's known as x87.

Today's x86 CPUs functionally can do all the same things as the 8086, only much faster and they don't carry some of the 8086 bugs. There are very few things that Intel/AMD don't want to continue supporting or already chose not to (e.g. undocumented and duplicate instructions and some instructions and instruction encodings in 64-bit mode, but 64-bit mode is not your normal x86 and for that reason is commonly referred to as x86/64 or x64).

If you're asking why the CPU numbering doesn't appear very sequential (e.g. a better 8086 would've been 8087 and then 8088 and 8089), I don't know. But how important is that, really?

Comment: wikipedia says > The "5" in the model number came from the fact that the 8085 requires only a +5-volt (V) power supply rather than the +5V, −5V and +12V supplies the 8080 needed.

Comment: and it also says > Both the architecture and the physical chip were therefore developed rather quickly by a small group of people, and using the same basic microarchitecture elements and physical implementation techniques as employed for the slightly older 8085 (and for which the 8086 also would function as a continuation).

Comment: ok so that's the reason why they didn't make it as 80185 , 80285 but instead it's 80186 , 80286 , 80386 and etc for x86 cpu

Comment: @caramel23 If your question has been answered, don't forget to accept the best answer.

Comment: @caramel23, yes, but 80186 was almost only used for embedded devices. September 2007 Intel stopped making them. :-)

Comment: Changing a more significant digit seems to be a marketing factor. Would you rather buy a processor that is +100 better than the old version of +1 better? MIPS did "better" (R2000, R3000, R4000, R8000, R10000); Alpha (21x64) and Motorola 68k (680x0) are other examples. This also has the benefit of allowing auxiliary chips (e.g., coprocessors, memory controllers, cache controllers) to use variation in the less significant digits making it clearer that they associate with the specific processor. LSdigits can also be used for processor variants (e.g., 8086 with 8-bit bus: 8088).

Answer (score 0):

Well actually 8085 architecture is actually a 8-bits microprocessor and follows a 8bits architecture while the 8086 is actually a 16-bits microprocessor and it's architecture is known as x86 architecture the similarity between those is mainly found in their mnemonics or that ASM codes generally. Nowadays generally 32-bits system even share the same architecture of x86